# Implementation of a C pre-processor in Python or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, c, preprocessor

Is there a known implementation of the C pre-processor tool implemented either in Python or JavaScript? I am looking for a way to robustly pre-process C (and C like) source code and want to be able to process, for example, conditional compilation and macros *without* invoking an external CPP tool or native code library. Another potential use case is pre-processing within a web application, within the web browser.

So far, I have found implementations in [Java](http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/), [Perl](http://www.anarres.org/projects/cpp/), and of course, [C](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/) and [C](http://spinroot.com/gerard/) again. It may be plausible to use one of the [C to JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/emscripten/) compilers now becoming available.

The PLY (Python Lex and Yacc) tools include a **cpp implemented in [Python](http://code.google.com/p/ply/source/browse/trunk/ply/cpp.py)**.

Comment: "An external CPP tool" is normally built right into the compiler. What do you need this for?

Comment: That seems lot a lot of work for not a lot of gain.  Why would this matter?

Comment: You **could** always implement this yourself -- the preprocessor is exceedingly simple (in fact, I believe it is regular, so you'd not even need context free grammars in order to interpret it).

Comment: @billy The preprocessor is not simple, once macros are considered: and then line splicing, comment stripping, pragmas, token concatenation, and arithmetic are supported. @ira To perform source code analysis / manipulation in contexts where invoking an external tool is not possible e.g. in a browser, or in pure python. @karl I need a pre-processor independent of a given compiler, since I am not in fact seeking to compile, but rather process code, when the compiler is not available.

Comment: Any particular reason why you require python or javascript?  If you decide to implement it yourself, I would recommend using a [parsing expression grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) library such as [treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) for ruby.

Comment: I am using python parser tools currently (PLY) and want to integrate preprocessing. JS would work in the web front end in browser.

Comment: @Billy: It took me just over a month's worth of effort to implement most of the preprocessor in C++ (I omitted some things like multicharacter literals and UCNs). All told it was over 4,000 lines of very concise C++, not including the test suite.  Macro replacement is exceedingly convoluted. At a bare minimum, you need a lexer, conditional stack, macro replacer, file manager, expression parser, expression evaluator, and a bucket of smaller components.  You also have to account for C90, C99, C++03, and C++0x.

Comment: @Billy: I second James.  We have preprocessor implemented for static analysis and source code transformation tools for C and C++; ours is some 10K SLOC but also allows us to expand/not expand arbitrary parts. This lets expand away only the "bad" conditionals or macros, retaining the structured ones, which lets us analyze the code mostly with the preprocessor directives in place. If you throw away that capability, I'm sure ours would be roughly the same size as James'. And its convoluted code. This just isn't a trivial thing to do.

Comment: @grrussel: If you are using Python, then invoking a preprocessor shouldn't be an issue; I assume it can shell out.  Is there a world in which it can't?   I don't think building a static analysis tool in Javascript is a good idea; C/C++ programs turn out to be pretty big when you process the include files they reference, and you'll want decent performance in the preprocess/parse part, as well as the analysis part.

Comment: @ira Performance of the static analysis is probably largely down to total program size: I am interested in analysis of OpenCL code, which is essentially C99 + extensions, but with a typical program size of 10s to 100s of lines; a 1000 line program is very atypical. They do, however, often use preprocessor features. As for when not to shell out, I am trying to split analysis between a web UI and a webservice in python, where the program source is untrusted; I am unsure if there are more issues than #include /etc/passwd in using CPP directly, but would prefer to do preprocessing client side.

Comment: @grrussel: So maybe I take back my remark about implementing the preprocessor.  I'd guess that most OpenCL program don't use the dark corners of the preprocessor much; if you belive that, you can implement just the basics (still a bit of work) and only offend a very small part of your audience.   But I still wouldn't recommend doit it this way.  Your program ...

Comment: @grrussel ... architecture has a UI and webservice; the usual best practice is to put the business logic ("BL") (e.g., anything but presentation) into the server, because otherwise you'll find BL in the UI will eventually have complicated interactions with the BL in the server. For instance, the macro names may someday become important to your linter; now the UI, doing macro expansion and making them vanish, will have to pass them to the server.

Comment: @ira Indeed, the web ui is simply one way to interact with the analysis (a library accepting preprocessed source): for local use, use of a local preprocessor on the command line is not unsafe, and not (very) problematic assuming the preprocessor doesn't violate a few OpenCL specific edge cases.

Comment: Over on GitHub: [ned14/pcpp](https://github.com/ned14/pcpp), [paulross/cpip](https://github.com/paulross/cpip), [interpreters/pypreprocessor](https://github.com/interpreters/pypreprocessor), [Lambosaurus/py-c-preprocessor](https://github.com/Lambosaurus/py-c-preprocessor) ... the first one would also be my favorite. They didn't exist back when the question was asked, AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply), an implementation of Lex and Yacc on Python which contains a [cpp tool implemented in python](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/master/ply/cpp.py) using the PLY lexer. There is also [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser), a parser built on top of PLY for the C language.

Comment: Sadly, pycparser does not support C code except after the preprocessor has been invoked on it.

Comment: pycparser can [invoke the preprocessor for you](https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pycparser/#interaction-with-the-c-preprocessor)

Answer (score 7):

Check out [pypreprocessor](https://github.com/interpreters/pypreprocessor)

It can also be found on [PYPI (Python Package Index)](https://pypi.org/project/pypreprocessor/) so it can be downloaded directly using pip.

If you're looking to use #define and #ifdef statements to do simple conditional compilation it should meet your needs. You can either run it as a standalone script and specify an input file (that can be in any language) to process or you can import it as a python module and use it to self-consume python source.

pypreprocessor does **not** support:

- macro replacement
- logical operations (Ie. || &&)
- mathematical operations (Ie. + - * /)
- multiline preprocessor directives

It's a tool designed specifically for conditional compilation, not metaprogramming.

Here's an example of how to process a C file using pypreprocessor as a standalone script:

```
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor

pypreprocessor.defines.append('debug')
pypreprocessor.input = 'input_file.c'
pypreprocessor.output = 'output_file.c'
pypreprocessor.removeMeta = True

pypreprocessor.parse()
```

The implementation is pretty simple.

**defines.append('debug'):**

Has the same effect as adding a '#define debug' directive to the file. This is just a convenient way to set defines.

**pypreprocessor.input = 'input_file.c':**

Sets the file you want to process.

**pypreprocessor.output = 'output_file.c':**

Sets where the file is output to.

**pypreprocessor.removeMeta = True:**

Removes all of the preprocessor directives found in the file. This includes all #define, #ifdef, #undefine, #else, etc. from the source file. This is useful for creating a 'clean' production version of the source minus all of the conditional code and directives that aren't used. This step is also completely optional. If you don't add this any code that doesn't fall within a defined condition will automatically be commented out.

For example:

```
#define debug

#ifdef debug
print('this will appear in the postprocessed code')
#else
#print('this will be commented out in the postprocessed code')
#endif
```

If you need macro replacement to, for instance, change source from one language to another pyprocessor doesn't support this yet. In theory, it wouldn't take much work to add but the lexer would need to be extended first to skip keywords that appear within text strings.

*SideNote: It's also compatible with both python2x and python3k.*

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of pypreprocessor.*

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox build system does something similar for its chrome. A source file named jar.mn lists all the XUL/JS files needed, and optionally these files are preprocessed before they are shipped. Thus the script that [ships](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/config/JarMaker.py) the files also invokes a mini-[preprocessor](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/config/Preprocessor.py).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to create a python binding around the clang c preprocessor.

Comment: libclang comes with Python bindings nowadays.  See
[Parsing C++ in Python with Clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/).

Answer (score 0):

If ANTLR can be used with Python/Javascript (I highly doubt the latter), you can get a grammar from the ANTLR site: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1166665121622/Cpp.tar

If not, it might be be a good start anyway - simply convert it to a grammar understood by your favourite parser generator.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hard part of implementing a preprocessor is the custom logic that must be written for macro replacement and constrained-range expression evaluation.